# Radio and Checkbox Inputs Not Working With scrollOverflow=true (On Mobile Only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, checkbox, radio-button

**WHAT I AM USING?**

I am using FullPage.js with scrollOverflow.

**MY SETTINGS**

These are my settings

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //Navigation
        sectionsColor: ['#06C', '#C06', '#930', '#06C'],
        anchors: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
        menu: '.menu',
        navigation: true,
        scrollOverflow: false, /* True or False Depending */
        scrollBar: true,
        fixedElements: '.header',
        paddingTop: '3em',
        slidesNavigation: true,
        paddingBottom: '1em'
            });
});
</script>
```

**PROBLEM EXPLANATION**

I have a contact form that has radio and checkboxes inputs but those inputs don't work in mobile devices with scrollOverflow equals to true. They work on desktops though.

If I chancge scrollOverflow to false the inputs work on mobile but scrollOverflow does not works which is needed because the contact form is long for mobile.

**LIVE EXAMPLES**

You can see scrollOverflow=true (enable) on this live example 1 but radio and checkbox inputs don't work on mobile.

1. https://gramerlab.com/a1.html

On these example 2 I disabled scrollOverflow=false and the radio and checkbox inputs work on mobile but the scrollOverflow don't works which is bad if the contact form is long and I need to scroll.

2. https://gramerlab.com/a2.html

**Does anyone knows how to fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

I just had to add the following lines inside my Internal Script

```
scrollOverflowOptions: {
   click:false, 
   preventDefaultException: {tagName: /.*/}
}
```

**Originally I had this:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //Navigation
        sectionsColor: ['#06C', '#C06', '#930', '#06C'],
        anchors: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
        menu: '.menu',
        navigation: true,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        scrollBar: true,
        fixedElements: '.header',
        paddingTop: '3em',
        slidesNavigation: true,
        paddingBottom: '1em',
    });
});
</script>
```

**Now I have this:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //Navigation
        sectionsColor: ['#06C', '#C06', '#930', '#06C'],
        anchors: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
        menu: '.menu',
        navigation: true,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        scrollBar: true,
        fixedElements: '.header',
        paddingTop: '3em',
        slidesNavigation: true,
        paddingBottom: '1em',
        scrollOverflowOptions: {
            click:false,    
            preventDefaultException: {tagName: /.*/}
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

**I tested in iPhone, Android and Kindle Fire Devices.
In all of them, the test was successful.**